Is there an issue with parsing UUIDs for GraphQL requests?
I am trying to make some automatic GraphQL API tests using the Starlette TestClient in Python. My issue is that my GraphQL schema has a query that needs a UUID! as an input, say
testQuery(id: UUID!): String

So I defined a suitable query
query test($id: UUID!) {
  testQuery(id: $id) {
    result
  }
}

and wanted to set a dictionary for the variables through:
variables = {'id': str(uuid.uuid4())}

and call:
client.post("/graphql", json={"query": query, "variables": variables)

I fear that the UUID is not getting parsed correctly as I get the following error in the response:
"errors":[{"message":"\'123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000\'"...

